Can I Switch the Limit Operator and the Integral in: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+(nx^{n-1})^{2}}dx$
I know the integral evaluates to $2$*, but how can I prove that? Do I have to show that the function is continuous to swap the limit and integral? Or is there a much simpler way of showing this? Thanks.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+(nx^{n-1})^{2}}dx$$

If you show that the sequence of function $(1+nx^{n-1})_n$ is increasing monotone (with respect to $n$) $\forall x\in (0,1)$, then the swap is allowed by the monotone convergence theorem.

Previously asked here by the OP. Also, the limit seems to be $2$

To evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(n x^{n-1}\right)^2} \, dx,
$$
we can interpret the integral geometrically.
The expression inside the integral represents the arc length of the curve $y = x^n$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. Let's analyze the behavior of this curve as $n \to \infty$.
For $x$ in the interval $[0, 1)$, the term $x^n$ approaches 0 very rapidly as $n$ becomes large. This suggests that for most of the interval $[0, 1)$, the curve $y = x^n$ is almost horizontal and lies very close to the $x$-axis.
At $x = 1$, however, we have $y = 1^n = 1$ regardless of the value of $n$. As $n \to \infty$, the transition from $y \approx 0$ for $x < 1$ to $y = 1$ at $x = 1$ becomes increasingly sharp, effectively becoming a vertical segment at $x = 1$.
Therefore, for large $n$, the curve $y = x^n$ approximates a path that is nearly a straight horizontal line from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$, followed by a vertical line from $(1, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$. The length of this path is simply the sum of the horizontal distance, which is 1, and the vertical distance, which is also 1. Thus, the total arc length approaches 2.
Consequently, we conclude that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(n x^{n-1}\right)^2} \, dx = \boxed{2}.
$$

It is possible to find the limit without referring to the length of the graph. We have $$I_n:=\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{1+(nx^{n-1})^2}\,dx \le \int\limits_0^1[{1+nx^{n-1}]}\,dx=2$$ Fix $0<a<1.$ Then $$I_n\ge \int\limits_0^{a}1\,dx+\int\limits_a^1 nx^{n-1}\,dx=a+(1-a^n)$$ Thus $\liminf_nI_n\ge a+1.$ As $a$ is arbitrary we get $\liminf_nI_n\ge 2.$

If we take $a=\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n}}$, then $$I_n\geq\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n}}+1-\frac1n\to2.$$

It seems that the sequences ${I_n}$ is strictly increasing and $$\sup_{n\geq1}I_n=2.$$ Can you give some advice on the $monotonicity$? Thank you!

@Riemann I do not know how to prove the monotonicity at the moment, although I have impression that the graph of $y=x^n$ is konger than that of $y=x^{n-1}.$

@
Ryszard Szwarc Yes, It is indeed, as you said.

Too long for a comment
$$I(n)=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+(nx^{n-1})^2}dx=n\int_0^1\sqrt{1/{n^2}+(x^{n-1})^2}dx\overset{t=x^{n-1}}{=}\frac n{n-1}\int_0^1\sqrt{1/{n^2}+t^2}t^{-\frac{n-2}{n-1}}dt$$
$$\overset{t=\frac xn}{=}\frac n{n-1}\frac{n^{\frac{n-2}{n-1}}}{n^2}\int_0^n\sqrt{1+x^2}x^{\frac1{n-1}-1}dx=\frac{n^{-\frac1{n-1}}}{n-1}\int_0^n\sqrt{1+x^2}x^{\frac1{n-1}-1}dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\sqrt{1+x^2}x^\frac1{n-1}\bigg|_0^n-n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\int_0^n\frac{x^{\frac1{n-1}+1}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
$$=\sqrt{1+n^2}+n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\int_0^n\frac{x^{\frac1{n-1}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\big(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\big)dx-n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\int_0^nx^{\frac1{n-1}}dx$$
$$\sqrt{1+n^2}-(n-1)+n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\int_0^n\frac{x^{\frac1{n-1}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)}dx$$
$$\overset{x=\sinh t}{=}\sqrt{1+n^2}-(n-1)+n^{-\frac1{n-1}}\int_0^{\ln(n+\sqrt{1+n^2})}\sinh^{\frac1{n-1}}(t)\,e^{-t}dt\tag{1}$$
The set of functions $f_n=e^{-t}\,\sinh^{\frac1{n-1}}(t)\chi_{[0;\ln(n+\sqrt{1+n^2})]}$ for $n>3$ is dominated by $e^{-t+1}$.
Taking the limit under the integral sign
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I(n)=1+\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt=2$$
Using the representation (1) we can find the asymptotic of the integral at $n\to\infty$ ; the evaluation is straightforward. For example, next couple of terms gives
$$I(n)=2-\frac{\ln n}n+\frac{\ln2-1}n+O\Big(\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^2}\Big)$$
what is confirmed numerically by WA (for example, here and here )

PaulS already provided a solution for this particular integral, but I will give a more general answer.
A limit can be moved inside an integral but only when certain conditions are met. There are many theorems for this but the two most applicable are the Monotone convergence theorem and the Dominated convergence theorem.
I say these are the most applicable because most others are either special cases of these two or only applicable in very niche circumstances.
If the Wikipedia articles are too technical for you, here is a good resource from the University of Wisconsin.
